# nodejs supertest express test prior to invoking external API

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Not sure if this is possible but Id like to run a test without invoking an external API POST request.

Whats currently happening is ive got a test confirming the post data sent to my server API is processed correctly, as it needs to add some basic additional information to the BODY before sending it to the external API, and then the server makes another POST request to an external API with this modified BODY.

This is all done in the below function.

```
createUser(req,res){
...
// schema validation,

// adding fields

// external server post request


}
```

Is it possible to have my test ignore the external API call?

the test looks like

```
    it('POST users --> 200 Successful Post', () => {
        return request(app).post('/api/users').send(........ my json .......)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200)    
        .then((response) => {
            expect(response.body).toEqual(
                ......
            )
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) to intercept and mock requests for testings.

> On your test, you can setup your mocking object like this:
>
> ```js
> const nock = require("nock");
>
> const scope = nock("https://api.github.com")
>     .get("/repos/atom/atom/license")
>     .reply(200);
> ```
>
> It will intercept an HTTPS GET requests to `/repos/atom/atom/license`.

[How to Test Node.js Apps That Interact With External APIs](https://betterprogramming.pub/testing-nodejs-apps-that-interact-with-external-apis-with-nock-97e1957e4130)